# Browser freezes when sending Ajax request in loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, for-loop, each

First of all I know there are many same questions like this one but my issue is little different as compare to other. Actually the issue is that I am sending an ajax request inside a loop and when ever the script runs and reaches that loop part the browser freezes now I need that loop for sure but I wanted to know is there any way that request works without freezing my browser. here is the code I have written

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", '#start-backup', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Uploading folders and directories setting.
  var $ = jQuery;
  $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
  // Renaming the folder name
  var folderName = $(this).parentsUntil('#backup-settings').find('#zipName').val();
  var domain = window.location.hostname;
  var dt = new Date();
  var dateTime = dt.getDay() + "-" + dt.getMonth() + "-" + dt.getFullYear() + "-" + dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();
  if (folderName !== '') {
    var folder = domain + '_' + folderName + '_' + dateTime;
  } else {
    var folder = domain + '_' + dateTime;
  }

  var ftp_dir = $(this).attr('data-ftp-directory');
  var s3_dir = $(this).attr('data-s3-directory');
  var drive_dir = $(this).attr('data-drive-directory');
  var dropbox_dir = $(this).attr('data-dropbox-directory');

  var source = $(this).attr('data-source');

  // Uploading Basic Settings.
  var type = $('#type').find('.active').attr('data-value');
  var component = $('#component').find('.active').attr('data-value');
  var schedule = $('#schedule').find('.active').attr('data-value');

  if (schedule === 'schedule') {
    var scheduleType = $('#SchedulePane').find('.active input').val();

    if (scheduleType === 'monthly') {
      var dated = $('#sc_date').val();
      var day = $('#sc_day').val();
      var hour = $('#M-H').val();
      var min = $('#M-M').val();
      var am = $('#M-T').val();
    } else if (scheduleType === 'weekly') {
      var dt = new Date();
      var dated = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + parseInt(dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate();
      var day = $('#W-D').val();
      var hour = $('#W-H').val();
      var min = $('#W-M').val();
      var am = $('#W-T').val();
    } else if (scheduleType === 'daily') {
      var dt = new Date();
      var dated = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + parseInt(dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate();
      var day = '';
      var hour = $('#D-H').val();
      var min = $('#D-M').val();
      var am = $('#D-T').val();
    } else if (scheduleType === 'hourly') {
      var dt = new Date();
      var dated = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + parseInt(dt.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dt.getDate();
      var day = '';
      var hour = '';
      var min = '';
      var am = '';
    }
  }

  var storedIn = $('.storedIn').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-value');
  }).get();

  if (component == 'partial') {
    var allComponents = $("#partial_params .active-color").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();
  }
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      action: 'create_zip',
      folder: folderName,
      ftp_dir: ftp_dir,
      s3_dir: s3_dir,
      drive_dir: drive_dir,
      dropbox_dir: dropbox_dir,
      source: source,
      component: component,
      allComponent: allComponents,
      storeIn: storedIn,
      scheduleType: scheduleType,
      schedule: schedule,
      date: dated,
      day: day,
      hour: hour,
      min: min,
      am: am,
      btype: type
    },
    success: function() {

      if (schedule === 'schedule') {
        location.reload(true);
      } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
          url: ajaxurl,
          type: 'GET',
          async: false,
          data: {
            action: 'get_zip_count'
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var total = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {

              var progress = parseInt(i) / parseInt(total) * parseInt(100);
              jQuery('.progress-bar').css("width", progress + '%;');

              jQuery.each(storedIn, function(key, value) {
                if (value === 'ftp') {
                  var action = 'moko_upload_to_ftp';
                  var dir = ftp_dir;
                } else if (value === 'dropbox') {
                  var action = 'moko_upload_to_dropbox';
                  var dir = dropbox_dir;
                } else if (value === 's3') {
                  var action = 'moko_upload_to_s3';
                  var dir = s3_dir;
                } else if (value === 'drive') {
                  var action = 'moko_upload_to_drive';
                  var dir = drive_dir;
                }
                jQuery.ajax({
                  url: ajaxurl,
                  type: 'GET',
                  async: false,
                  data: {
                    action: action,
                    dir: dir,
                    file_name: jQuery(location).attr('host') + '_' + folderName + '-' + i
                  },
                  success: function() {
                    if (i === total - 1) {
                      jQuery.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: false,
                        data: {
                          action: 'store_backup',
                          folder: folderName,
                          ftp_dir: ftp_dir,
                          s3_dir: s3_dir,
                          drive_dir: drive_dir,
                          dropbox_dir: dropbox_dir,
                          component: component,
                          allComponent: allComponents,
                          storeIn: storedIn
                        },
                        success: function() {
                          location.reload(true);
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The real issue starts when my request reached that upload section where there are two loops. Any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Comment: The browser freeze is because you're using `async: false`. Never do that. Also note that sending AJAX requests in a loop is also a really bad idea; you're just going to flood your own server. Collate all the data into a single request instead.

Comment: Sir I can't collate all the data in a single request as I have multiple zip files which is uploaded to cloud servers and if I remove `async: false` then all the requests are sent at once and server timeout issue occurs

Comment: In which case I'd suggest you re-architect the solution as the way you're doing it now is incorrect. Without knowing the limitations of your server, or what the goal you're attempting reach is we can't really help you.

Comment: After so many attempts I made this code work as per the instructions now the only issue left is this browser freeze issue I don't want the browser to get freeze as I also wanted to show the progress bar and when browser freezes that progress bar don't work

Comment: Re architect requires alot of time and this is the only thing I don't have right now. :(

Comment: Anyways thank you so much for your time and knowledge and +1 for that little extra information on why browser is freezing.

Comment: you can use `Deferred` concept instead of `async`

Comment: " I don't want the browser to get freeze" in that case you have to remove `async:false`...there is no other way. So ultimately you have to re-think your code.

Comment: " I can't collate all the data in a single request as I have multiple zip files"...it's perfectly possible to upload multiple files in one request. Of course the server must be expecting it, and file size limitations could be an issue but in principle it's completely possible. If that's not possible, and you have to make multiple ajax requests and avoid overloading the server, then look into _chaining_ your requests - i.e. don't start a new request until the previous one has completed. $.ajax implements the Promise interface, so this is easy using .done() etc

Comment: @ADyson sir I am trying this with `done()` I'll post the result here as soon as it gets completed

Comment: Yes if you can solve it please post it in the Answers section for everyone to see. Thanks. If you can't solve it completely you can always update the question with your new code and explain the latest problem.

Comment: Sure I will post the answer as now I got something in mind to get rid of this issue don't know yet whether it's a proper solution or just a work around but I'll post the answer